# NPE in setAdapter()

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have got the method to display dialog with listview. Here is my code:
the method:

```
private void showWindow(){
Bitmap [] img = {dz, rz, s, ww};
Dialog builder = new Dialog(myContext);
builder.setTitle("to jest list view");
CustomList adapter = new CustomList(myContext, 
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, img);
builder.setContentView(R.layout.wybierz_kolor);
ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
builder.show();
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        break;
    case 3:
        break;
    }
}
});}
```

but in line "listView1.setAdapter(adapter);" I have got NPE. I searched but nothing. Maybe I forgot something, I don't know. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `ListView` is inside Dialog layout so use Dialog context to initialize `listView1` after `setContentView` as:

```
ListView listView1 = (ListView)builder.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

Comment: @user978758 : [android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml) layout uses TextView instead of ImageView to show rows in ListView so if you want to use any other View instead of TextView(like in your case ImageView) then you will need to create an custom Adapter by extending any available Adapters

Comment: I have got custom adapter:public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
 private final Context context;
 private final Bitmap [] obrazki;
 public CustomList(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
   Bitmap[] obrazki) {
  super(context, textViewResourceId);
  this.context = context;
  this.obrazki = obrazki;
 }

Comment: and getView method: @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wybierz_kolor_obrazek, null);
  ImageView iv = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
  iv.setImageBitmap(obrazki[position]);
  return rowView;
 }